# Does a suit fit in a carry-on bag or rollaboard?

Tags: air-travel, trains, luggage, gear

Usually, I travel with a bag pack, big enough for several weeks.

Times goes on, and I have to travel in a more urban way. I want to buy a roller bag fitting the cabin size of an average airplane. But in this case, I need one or two suits with me.

Does a suit fit an average cabin bag or do I need something bigger? I hate to carry them by hand. Or is there any other solution to travel with 1-2 suits?

The way should work while travling with trains and/or with air-planes.

Comment: Unless you want to fold your suit, they won't fit inside the cabin luggage, mine barely fit inside my check in luggage

Comment: Folding is okay for me.

Comment: Well then why wouldn't it fit?

Comment: Folding only once ;) I don't know. i never owned a cabin trolley...

Comment: Well you'll have to at least fold it twice, once won't do the trick. So, you'll have to make it a quarter. Cabin luggage is pretty spacious and should be able to fit 1 suit if you're willing to compress it a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [good article](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/ways-carry-suit-airplane-106813.html) I found which would explain your options in detail. As far as options go, you have several. Now since you mentioned you don't want to do check in luggage, you can either carry it on you or in your cabin luggage.

- **Fold it Up** - This is what I usually do. Now I admit that doing the same in a cabin luggage is a little bit difficult but most cabin luggage which completely utilize the dimensions allowed on typical international flights would suffice. Of course you *will* have to fold your suit into a quarter to fit it in though.
- **Wear It!** - It's a great option especially because it shifts a lot of weight from your suitcase to yourself allowing you extra room to carry other stuff. The good part about this option is that you look great! The bad part, your suit might get wrinkled on a long flight (Not the best option if you have a meeting the next day).
- Roll It! - I haven't personally tried this one, but I'm a bit skeptical regarding whether the suit would not wrinkle or come out as mush. I wouldn't like to try this in the near future either though. But it does save a *lot* of space.
- Hanging Bag - I've tried this one too, but I wouldn't recommend it at all, simply because it's too painful and it might count as a separate item (akin to a laptop bag or a guitar). Policies on airlines differ regarding it as well, but it is theoretically the best way (for your suit) to do it.